# gltranslatef not quite working as expected

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I was under the impression that gl.glTranslatef() effectively moved a sprite by the values passed in to the method (ie if I wanted a sprite to move by 2 pixels I would call `gl.glTranslate(2.0f,0.0f,0.0f);`

However If I do this then the sprite remains static. However If I pass in an absolute position (ie call `gl.glTranslatef(52.0f,0.0f,0.0f)`) my sprite moves as expected. However its starting position is out by the initial position coordinates (ie If I specify the sprite to start at 30,30 then the first draw loop draws the sprite at 62,30, once the first frame is done the sprite moves as I expect.

What is going on?

here is the draw code for my sprite.

//Reset the modelview matrix
        gl.glLoadIdentity();

```
    //drawing


    //bind the previously generated texture
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,this._texture);

    //point to our buffers
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    //set the face rotation
    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);

    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glTranslatef(_position.x,_position.y,0.0f);//need to work out fraction of 1 that the position of the sprite represents

    //point to our vertex buffer
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, _vertexBuffer);

    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, _textureBuffer);


    //draw the vertices as a triangle strip
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, _vertices.length / 3);
    gl.glPopMatrix();
    //disable the client state before leaving
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
```

Note that this passes in the absolute position and not the small extra movement.

To simplify the above.

If I specify static inputs for gltranslatef

gl.glTranslatef(2.0f,2.0f,0.0f);

I would expect the matrix to move diagonally by 2 units each frame, however if I do this the matrix and hence my sprite stays at position 2,2

If I add 2 to the input parameters on each frame (ie 2, then 4 then 6 etc) my sprite moves diagonally but this is not how I thought translatef worked.

Comment: Ok, I think I may have worked out what is happening. I assumed that each time a tranlate is applied the vertices were saved in the new state, however it look like the vertices are always in the satet they were initialised in so as a result the translate is adding 2.0f to the original position rather than the last position? is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

culprits for the given behaviour in your case are `glPushMatrix()` and `glPopmatrix()`. These two calls restore the original state(matrix stack) every frame. So every time your origin remain same and when you specify `(2.0, 0.0,0.0)` each fram with respect to world origin your sprite remains at world origin. Remove these two calls and see the magic !